# How to permanently get rid of folder that keeps coming back on reboot

Tags: files, osx

I ran a virus scan with Clamxav on my mac a couple days ago and it picked up on a PUA (Potentially undated app). It was located in /Application Support/Generic/E18VMjMwVtTrc. There was and executable file and two empty .log files in there the first time. I deleted the folder and rebooted. When I rebooted, the folder came back. Only the executable file was not in there, just the 2 .log files. I keep deleting it and it comes back everytime. I have tried iosnoop, opensnoop, top, and other commands to no avail. Thanks for your help!